# Working with Core Data (multiple ViewControllers)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

There is 1 thing I don't completely understand about working with `CoreData` (and I can't find a good answer to my question): how do you use `CoreData` in an app with multiple `UIViewcontrollers` ?

At the moment I was playing around with core data in multiple controllers and I typed this in each `VC`:

```
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EntityName", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    let entityName = EntityName(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
```

But I don't think this is the best practice for working with `CoreData` on multiple controllers (*side question: does this have an impact on my app's preformance?*). What is the most preferred way?

1. Do I create a managed object context in each viewcontroller?
   *(Lots of copy-paste, like I'm doing now)*
2. Do I create a singleton for the creation of `CoreData` ? *I've read somewhere that this was not the preferred way*
3. Do I pass the managed object context to the next controller using
   segues (or set a public context variable in the app delegate's function `'*didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*'`)?
4. Something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

3-> Setting a public main queue MOC is a good practice. Because main queue is a serial queue.

1-> Using the main queue MOC only for fetching and creating child MOC for each editing is a good practice. Because editing MOCs that can be fetched may cause conflicts.

2-> You can try creating a singleton instance for getting the shared main queue MOC and define some functions that create child context for editing.

4-> But actually theres no best practice for abstract situations.

I think so.

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do is to avoid code duplication. Therefore just bring the code into one single function and place it somewhere. It could be an extension on `UIViewControler` or `AppDelegate` or just a helper function

This is how an extension on `UIViewController` would look like:

```
extension UIViewController
{
   func doCoreDataWork()
   {
       let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       let context = app.managedObjectContext
       let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EntityName", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
       let entityName = EntityName(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
   }
}
```

then call `doCoreDataWork()` from any view controller.

And no, it has nothing to do with performance